# How to pass data from Index.html to Svelte app?

Tags: svelte

Is there any way of passing a variable from index.html to the Svelte app? E.g. the names array below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'>
    <title>Svelte app</title>
    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/favicon.png'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bundle.css'>

    <script> var names = [ "Tom", "Dick", "Harry" ]; </script>
    <script defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason is that the Index.html is dynamically created, and I want to pass different data to the Svelte app to operate on that is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Just export the data in a module or use `globalThis`.  I just replied to someone with the details, so I'll just link [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76031247/use-variable-from-static-js-file-in-a-sveltekit-component/76032348#76032348).

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally new to Svelte. So after experimenting for while, I came up with this:

In Index.html, add an invisible element (e.g. <p>) with parameters in text. I used a JSON string for flexibility:

```
<body>
    <p id="jsonInitData" style="display: none;">{ "name": "tom", "age": 23 }</p>
</body>
```

Then in App.svelte, I fetch the string and parse it into a JS dictionary:

```
let jsonInitData = JSON.parse( document.getElementById( "jsonInitData" ).textContent );
console.log( "App.svelte called: jsonInitData", jsonInitData );
```

This will do for me for now. Hope it helps someone. If there's a more standard way of doing it, I'd love to know, because I couldn't find it.

Comment: Would use a `<script type="application/json">` instead, `p` is for paragraphs.