# Use variable from static .js file in a SvelteKit component

Tags: javascript, static, vite, sveltekit

I am trying to create a Chrome extension using SvelteKit and [sveltekit-adapter-chrome-extension](https://github.com/michmich112/sveltekit-adapter-chrome-extension). I have an `anilist_client.js` file under `/static` where I am declaring an `ANILIST_CLIENT` object that stores an ID an a SECRET that will later be used to access the [AniList API](https://anilist.gitbook.io/anilist-apiv2-docs/).

The file must be withing the /static directory so the user can replace the ID with their own without digging deep into the bundled code.

I tried to include the script in `app.html` and `<svelte:head>`, also followed [this guide](https://adamtuttle.codes/blog/2021/adding-3rd-party-script-tags-in-sveltekit/). All I got was "anilist_client is not defined".

```js
// static/anilist_client.js

const anilist_client = {
    id: '<id>',
    secret: '<secret>'
};
```

```js
// src/lib/components/Options.svelte

<script>
    console.log(anilist_client.secret);
</script>

<a href='https://anilist.co/api/v2/oauth/authorize?client_id={anilist_client.id}&response_type=token'>Login with AniList</a>
```

```html
// src/app.html

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%sveltekit.assets%/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="/anilist_client.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="%sveltekit.assets%/anilist_client.js"></script> -->
    %sveltekit.head%
</head>
```

```js
// svelte.config.js

import chromeExtensionAdapter from 'sveltekit-adapter-chrome-extension';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: chromeExtensionAdapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: null,
            precompress: false,
            manifest: 'manifest.json',
        }),
        appDir: 'ext',
    }
};

export default config;
```

Is there a way to access this object from my components that will run both in development and production bundle? Feels like I am missing something very obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to define a global variable using `const`.  If anything, I think you should be using `var`, and not const.

But I digress because there are better alternatives.  Right off the bat, you could just attach your `aniList_client` object to the global object, usually `window` in browsers.  Try this:

```js
globalThis.aniList_client = {
    id: blah,
    secret: blahblah
}
```

Then access it the same way (`globalThis.aniList_client`).

The other option would be to make your static JS a ESM module and load it as such in `<head>`:

```html
<head>
    ...
    <script src="/aniList_client.js" type="module"></script>
    ...
</head>
...
```

Then you would write said file as an ESM that exports your data:

```js
export default const aniList_client = {
    ...
};
```

The latter would probably require you to signal `rollup` or `webpack` that your module is external.  I don't have the specifics for this, though.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately, none of these worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I finally find a way to make it work:

First, I moved `anilist_client.js` from `static/` to `src/lib/anilist_client.ts`, so I could easily import it from my components:

```ts
// src/lib/components/Options.svelte

<script>
    import anilist_client from '$lib/anilist_client';
    import '$lib/anime';

    console.log(anilist_client.secret);
</script>

<main>
    <a href='https://anilist.co/api/v2/oauth/authorize?client_id={anilist_client.id}&response_type=token'>Login with AniList</a>
</main>
```

The next step was to add `anilist_client.ts` to `build.rollupOptions.input` in `vite.config.ts`:

```ts
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        input: {
            anilist_client: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/lib/anilist_client.ts', import.meta.url)),
        }
    }
}
```

Since Sveltekit seems to override the `build.output.*FileNames` Vite options, in order for it to work with Chrome's background script, I ended up writing a Vite plugin to remove the hash from the generated .js files, so I can refer to background.js in manifest.json. Thanks to [raduab](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/7058) and [wallw-teal](https://github.com/michmich112/sveltekit-adapter-chrome-extension/issues/26).

```js
// remove-hash-from-entry.js

export default function removeHashFromSvelteKitEntryFiles(config) {
    return {
        name: 'remove-hash-from-sveltekit-entry-files',
        apply: 'build',
        enforce: 'post',

        config(config) {
            config.build.rollupOptions.output.entryFileNames =
                config.build.rollupOptions.output.entryFileNames.replace('[hash]', ``);

            return config;
        }
    }
}
```

```ts
// vite.config.ts

import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import removeHashFromSvelteKitEntryFiles from './remove-hash-from-entry';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit(), removeHashFromSvelteKitEntryFiles()],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                anilist_client: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/lib/anilist_client.ts', import.meta.url)),
                background: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/lib/background.ts', import.meta.url)),
                anime: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/lib/anime.ts', import.meta.url))
            },
            preserveEntrySignatures: 'strict',
        }
    }
});
```

There are probably better ways, but this was the first one to work after two days of research.